# Problem with XStream Marshalling to return xml and json

Tags: xml, json, class, marshalling, xstream

When i use

```
new XStream().toXml(someObject);
```

it returns following xml...

```
<response>
        <status>SUCCESS</status>
        <isOwnershipVerified class="boolean">false</isOwnershipVerified>
</response>
```

and, when i use

```
new XStream(new JsonHierarchicalStreamDriver()).toXml(someObject);
```

it returns following json...

```
{"response": {
  "status": "SUCCESS",
  "isOwnershipVerified": {
    "@class": "boolean""false"}
}}
```

Now, since i want to get rid of class attribute altogether (read it not to alias it with anything else, but to remove it) i use following code.

```
    XStream xStream = new XStream();
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    xStream.marshal(this, new PrettyPrintWriter(writer) {
        @Override
        public void addAttribute(final String key, final String value)
        {
            if (!key.equals("class"))
            {
                super.addAttribute(key, value);
            }
        }
    });
    return writer.toString();
```

which gives follwing xml...

```
<response>
        <status>SUCCESS</status>
        <isOwnershipVerified>false</isOwnershipVerified>
</response>
```

but, when i pass new JsonHierarchicalStreamDriver() while xStream object creation above, it does NOT return json. it returns the same xml shown above.

What is wrong going on here?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out...

instead of using

```
new PrettyPrintWriter(writer) ...
```

use

```
new JsonHierarchicalStreamWriter(writer)
```

and the things will start working as expected... :D